# Creating a file just to be uploaded into the online form

Tags: java, file, selenium

couldn't find relevant question on SO I'm asking a new one. I can create a file using `FileWriter` class, but it requires to specify the path for that file (physically creates the file). What I want to achieve is to create a file like in-memory, without specyfying the path or saving it on the disk and then upload it into the online form with selenium webdriver, is that somehow possible?

But there also is another problem, html fileUpload element will accept the path such as:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Content_CV")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\name\\Documents\\my_cv.pdf");
```

but will it accept the file itself? Probably not, so assuming that some of you knows how to create a file without saving it on the disk, would there be a way of providing path to that file anyway (given its virtual location)?

I'm trying to figure it out and I did some google research, yet here I am. Thanks for any attempt of help :)

Comment: why not  create it,upload it and delete it??

Comment: That is an option that I will surely go for if what I'm asking for is impossible.

Comment: What about [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: I will check it out now

Comment: @tobias_k: This will still create a file on your disk. [see API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @tobias_k: Thats not a problem but nor what he asked for: "_What I want to achieve is to create a file like in-memory_"

Comment: @MrSmith42 I know what he _asked_ for, but maybe that's not what he [_really needs_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I proposed it as an alternative.

Comment: @tobias_k - that worked. Perhaps I didn't say very well what I meant, I know that file is being stored on the drive, but it doesn't require a path such as on my machine I  would use C:\path and it wouldn't work on the other. Anyway it's working fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is just how to create a temporary file without caring about how to name it and where to create it without overwriting existing files, then you can simply use [`File.createTempFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). This will create an actual new temporary file on disk in the directory designated by the operating system for that purpose. You might also want to have a look at [`File.deleteOnExit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for a java solution, you can simply create the file in a [RAM drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) 
Software for this exist for all mayor operating systems.
Have a look at the wikipedia link above for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a Java solution for this :)